# Basis vectors and non-square matrix transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose we have a $2\times3$ matrix which takes a $3\times1$ column vector expressed in a basis $\mathcal{B}$. The output of this multiplication is a $2\times1$ vector. That is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}_\mathcal{B}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1' \\
x_2'
\end{bmatrix}_\text{basis?}$$
My question is what is the basis of this new vector?

If we take the vector:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}_\mathcal{B}$$
then it sends it in:
$$
\mathbf{x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Of course we can write $\mathbf{x}$ as:
$$
\mathbf{x}
=
a_1\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+
a_2
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

but we don't know the basis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{ v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ be the basis $\mathcal{B}$, and $T$ be the linear transformation represented by the multiplication. A preimage of $T$ is some vector $x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + x_3 v_3$, where $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ (or whatever field is relevant). The image is expressed with respect to a basis $\{w_1, w_2\}$, let's call it $\mathcal{C}$. This basis is such that $T v_1 = a_1 w_1 + a_2 w_2$, $T v_2 = b_1 w_1 + b_2 w_2$, and $T v_3 = c_1 w_1 + c_2 w_2$.

Comment: So if I understood it correctly, the matrix that represents the transformation depends on the basis of the input and output vector?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking given a finite spanning set $\mathcal{A}$, how one can find a subset of it that is a basis, one way to do this would be to start with the empty set and keep adding elements until the set you get spans the space(and then you stop).